# Azure Pipeline Unit Tests & Environment Variables

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-pipelines

Struggling to see another question with an answer for this. I have the following code in a unit test (variable names changed). This information is used in my integration tests

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddUserSecrets<MyTestTests>()
                .Build();

var option= new Option();

option.x1 = configuration.GetValue<string>("Option:x1");
option.x2 = configuration.GetValue<string>("Option:x2");
option.x3 = configuration.GetValue<string>("Option:x3");
option.x3= configuration.GetValue<string>("Option:x4");

return option;
```

This works fine locally when my unit tests are running locally. However, when my integration tests run in an Azure Pipeline it is not picking up the environment variables.

I have created them in the format of

*option__x1* where the _ is a double underscore.

If the Environment Variables are open then it works, however, if they are set as secret then it does not work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Pipeline Unit Tests & Environment Variables

This behavior is by designed for protecting secret variables from being exposed in the task.

[This documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables) states that secret variables are:

- **Not decrypted into environment variables. So scripts and programs run    by your build steps are not given access by default.**
- Decrypted for access by your build steps. So you can use them in    password arguments and also pass them explicitly into a script or a
  program from your build step (for example as $(password)).

That the reason why you could not use the secret variables in your task.

To resolve this issue, we need to explicitly map secret variables:

```
variables:
 GLOBAL_MYSECRET: $(mySecret) 
 GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: foo 

steps:

- powershell: |

  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # right way to map to an env variable
```

You could check [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/145) for and [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To use the secret variable in the **VSTest@3** task, you need to do the following steps:

Create a secret variable in your pipeline or variable group, ie:  **Password_Secret**.

Create a .runsettings file in your Visual Studio project and add a parameter with to reference the secret variable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="PASSWORD" value="secret" />
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

In your C# code, use the TestContext.Properties collection to access the secret variable:

```
var password = TestContext.Properties["PASSWORD"].ToString();
```

In your VSTest@3 task, specify the path to the .runsettings file in the runSettingsFile input.
In your VSTest@3 task, use the overrideTestrunParameters input to pass the secret variable to the .runsettings file:

```
  - task: VSTest@3
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*test*.dll
        !**\*TestAdapter.dll
        !**\obj\**
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      rerunFailedTests: true
      rerunMaxAttempts: '4'
      runSettingsFile: 'Project1.Test/Settings.runsettings'
      overrideTestrunParameters: '-PASSWORD $(Password_Secret)'
```